# Gemara, Rashi and Tosfos Shiurim to Download

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, adult-learning, daf-yomi

Hi I’m a buchor in yeshiva and I want to download shiurim that go in depth including Gemara, Rashi and Tosfos. Does anyone know any shiur I can listen to? Is there anyone that gives daf yomi with Gemara, Rashi and Tosfos?

Comment: https://shasilluminated.org/

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

[Daf Hachaim](https://dafhachaim.org/) is a shiur given on purely Gemara and Rashi (which he explains outside, but often nearly verbatim). He then has separate shiurim for each daf going through the Tosfos.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the links cited above, All Daf https://alldaf.org/ has audio covering the Daf and probably much of Rashi and Tosafot. It also has a feature where much of Tosafot is translated not sure if the project is finished, but it looks like they are covering all of Tosafot.

In addition to shiurim, here are 2 additional resources that I find extremely useful.

Sefaria is my goto source for learning Daf Yomi https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud has Rashi and Tosofot connected with small sections. Occasionally they are translated.

Daf Yomi Advancement Forum https://www.dafyomi.co.il/today.htm has over 90% of Tosafot translated.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us! Looks like the question was regarding *shiurim*, not translations, while your answer focuses on translations